# How can I include a NuGet package with native dlls in my new CSPROJ Class Library?

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, nuget, csproj

I have a class library which I just migrated to the new *csproj* format that has a dependency on [SQLite.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite.Core/).

*SQLite* has native dependencies `x64/SQLite.Interop.dll` and `x86/SQLite.Interoop.dll` which used to get copied to the output folder for any project adding my package. This was taken care of by *NuGet* by automatically including the following import in the old *csproj* file:

`<Import Project="..\packages\System.Data.SQLite.Core.1.0.106\build\net451\System.Data.SQLite.Core.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\System.Data.SQLite.Core.1.0.106\build\net451\System.Data.SQLite.Core.targets')" />`

After migrating to the new *csproj* I can build my library as a *NuGet* package which correctly includes [SQLite.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite.Core/) as a dependency however whoever consumes my *NuGet* library does not get the native dependencies coppied to the output folder.

On the other hand, if the consumer first adds the [SQLite.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite.Core/) then add my package everything works correctly.

Any idea how I can restore the behaviour before the migration? Below is the migrated *csproj*:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <PackageId>My.Library</PackageId>
    <Description>Some Library.</Description>        
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net452</TargetFramework>    
    <AssemblyName>My Library</AssemblyName>    
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>    
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SQLite.Core" Version="1.0.106" />
  </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    </ItemGroup>    

</Project>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `System.Data.SQLite.Core` uses build-time logic to include the package to the content, the default dependency settings for `PackageReference` aren't a good fit if you build a library referencing that package. By default, `PackageReference` will not forward contentFiles, build assets and analyzers for transitive references.

To change that behavior, edit your `PackageReference` to:

```
<PackageReference Include="System.Data.SQLite.Core" Version="1.0.106" PrivateAssets="none"/>
```

This will ensure that the package will behave exactly the same when reference directly or transitively via your library. In your specific case, `PrivateAssets` could also be `contentFiles;analyzers` since only `build` would need to be forwarded but since the package only contains `build` assets, it doesn't matter.

See [Controlling dependency assets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#controlling-dependency-assets) for more details.

Comment: Excellent, thank you for the explanation, worked great!

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not yet work with dotnet core! https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/tktview/d292f2e23d8a74e0e7619638a2ff1ccab973fffe